# How I can build user agent string based on real machine data on windows

Tags: internet-explorer, winapi, user-agent

I have windows application that use wininet functions for GET requests to my server.

Also I want to gather some statistic based on log files (IE version because I used IE components, Windows version, Net framework version).

Wininet allow to specify user-agent string in request body, but it doesn't provide default user-agent, so I need to build my self this string.

I want to build user-agent string based on the following template
Mozilla/(mozillaNumber).0 (compatible; MSIE (IEversion).0; Windows NT (winversion).(minorwinversion); (x64 flag); Trident/(trident version).0 myApplicationName)

and I didn't know how to get IE version, trident version without requesting administrative rights or is there function that do all work for me

Update: This is useful link http://www.enhanceie.com/ua.aspx, but seems to me it is not ok to write a lot of code that gathers information from the unpublished registry keys

Update2: [ObtainUserAgentString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775114) is what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [ObtainUserAgentString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775114) from urlmon.dll.

> The following example is a User-Agent HTTP request header sent by
>   Internet Explorer 7 on Windows XP with Office:
>
> ```
> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath.1)
> ```